# Scala macros evaluate Enumeration values

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

Given an Enumeration like this:

```
object Enum1 extends Enumeration {
  val value1, value2 = Value
  val value3 = Value("value3Name")

  val notNewAValue = value3

}
```

And an object like this:

```
@MyMacro
object MacroObject
```

How could I access the values of `Enum1` (or any other Enumeration passed as a parameter) in the macro annotation `MyMacro`?

When I say "values" I'm not considering `notNewAValue`, only `value1`, `value2` and `value3`.

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum

Comment: The thing with enumeratum is that it uses case objects as the values, but I need to use Scala enumerations

Comment: Why? sealed family are way more powerful.

Comment: I know sealed traits are much more powerful. But the problem I'm trying to solve needs to handle Scala enumerations that come from code I can't change